# An error occurred running the Unity content on this page

Tags: unity-game-engine

After Build and Run I get following error: It's a WebGL-Project. It doesn't work on firefox and chrome

```
An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser's JavaScript console for more info. The error was:
uncaught exception: abort(103) at jsStackTrace (Build.js:1:19540)
stackTrace (Build.js:1:19711)
abort (Build.js:3:29922)
vQl (Build.asm.js:28:1)
F7i (Build.asm.js:4:1)
LEk (Build.asm.js:15:1)
Fhj (Build.asm.js:4:1)
zEj (Build.asm.js:4:1)
IIi (Build.asm.js:8:1)
RKl (Build.asm.js:28:1)
invoke_iiii (Build.js:1:344272)
TVk (Build.asm.js:15:1)
qZk (Build.asm.js:19:1)
p6 (Build.asm.js:6:1)
o6 (Build.asm.js:6:1)
EZa (Build.asm.js:17:1)
BZa (Build.asm.js:17:1)
GZa (Build.asm.js:17:1)
KZa (Build.asm.js:17:1)
qsb (Build.asm.js:10:1)
ASa (Build.asm.js:17:1)
Bka (Build.asm.js:6:1)
oka (Build.asm.js:6:1)
uKl (Build.asm.js:28:1)
dynCall (Build.js:1:7469)
browserIterationFunc (Build.js:1:39097)
runIter (Build.js:1:42189)
Browser_mainLoop_runner (Build.js:1:40634)

If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
```

https://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/~doerflim/Spiele3D/SuperCube/